# Number of views increases for the question if the page refreshes. Is it a design intent?

Tags: support, bug, views

Number of views increases for the question if page refreshes. Is it a design intent?

Or increase number of views per question *only* when the non-current user views at once.

Comment: Of course it can increase after you refresh the page; other users might visit the page as well in the meantime. But even your own refreshes count, if they're more than 15 minutes apart.